# setParameter() not setting proper quotes

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have following code:

```
String searchText = "...";

String sqlQuery = 
        "FROM Studio s " +
        "WHERE fts('english', s.companyName, :q) = true";

    Query q = JPA.em()
            .createQuery(sqlQuery)
            .setParameter("q", searchText);
```

When I pass a single word to `searchText`, it works:

```
String searchText = "one";
```

When I pass two words, like

```
String searchText = "one two";
```

I get

> [PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:
>   could not execute query]

When I pass a quoted string however, it works again:

```
String searchText = "'one two'";
```

Is `SetParameter` not supposed to set proper quotes and escape the text?

P.S. `fts` is a PostgreSQL dialect function defined as follows:

```
public class MyPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect {
    public MyPostgreSQLDialect() {
       registerFunction("fts", new PostgreSQLFullTextSearchFunction());
    }
}
```

...

```
public class PostgreSQLFullTextSearchFunction implements SQLFunction {

   public String render(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List args, SessionFactoryImplementor factory) {
      if (args.size() != 3) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException(
               "The function must be passed 3 arguments");
      }

      String ftsConfig = (String) args.get(0);
      String field = (String) args.get(1);
      String value = (String) args.get(2);

      String fragment = null;
      if (ftsConfig == null) {
         fragment = "to_tsvector(" + field + ") @@ " + "to_tsquery('"
               + value + "')";
      } else {
         fragment = "to_tsvector(" + ftsConfig + "::regconfig, " + field + ") @@ "
               + "to_tsquery(" + ftsConfig + ", " + value + ")";
      }

      return fragment;

   }

   @Override
   public Type getReturnType(Type columnType, Mapping mapping)
         throws QueryException {
      return new BooleanType();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean hasArguments() {
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean hasParenthesesIfNoArguments() {
      return false;
   }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public String render(Type arg0, List arg1, SessionFactoryImplementor arg2)
            throws QueryException {
        return render(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

It converts the query into:

```
to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, studio0_.companyName) @@ to_tsquery('english', ?)
```

P.P.S.

PostreSQL log:

```
2014-02-11 15:10:39 CET ERROR:  syntax error in tsquery: "one two"
2014-02-11 15:10:39 CET STATEMENT:  select studio0_.uuid as uuid164_, studio0_.addressScore as addressS2_164_, studio0_.adwordsAktivity as adwordsA3_164_, studio0_.affDiversityScore as affDiver4_164_, studio0_.allSources as allSources164_, studio0_.backgroundImg as backgrou6_164_, studio0_.city as city164_, studio0_.clusterDiversityScore as clusterD8_164_, studio0_.companyName as companyN9_164_, studio0_.companyNameCount as company10_164_, studio0_.companyType as company11_164_, studio0_.completenessScore as complet12_164_, studio0_.contentTags as content13_164_, studio0_.crefoId as crefoId164_, studio0_.decisionMaker1 as decisio15_164_, studio0_.decisionMaker2 as decisio16_164_, studio0_.description as descrip17_164_, studio0_.email as email164_, studio0_.email2 as email19_164_, studio0_.emailCount as emailCount164_, studio0_.fax1 as fax21_164_, studio0_.fax2 as fax22_164_, studio0_.faxImpressum as faxImpr23_164_, studio0_.fbProfileUrl as fbProfi24_164_, studio0_.formOfAddress as formOfA25_164_, studio0_.hasGeoCode as hasGeoCode164_, studio0_.house as house164_, studio0_.imprintDataExtracted as imprint28_164_, studio0_.industry1 as industry29_164_, studio0_.industry2 as industry30_164_, studio0_.internetIq as internetIq164_, studio0_.internetIqCluster as interne32_164_, studio0_.lastActivityDelta as lastAct33_164_, studio0_.lastActivitySource as lastAct34_164_, studio0_.lastActivityTime as lastAct35_164_, studio0_.logoImg as logoImg164_, studio0_.mgUuid as mgUuid164_, studio0_.mgcUuid as mgcUuid164_, studio0_.minCriticalityLevel as minCrit39_164_, studio0_.numCheckins as numChec40_164_, studio0_.numLikes as numLikes164_, studio0_.numLocations as numLoca42_164_, studio0_.numMentions as numMent43_164_, studio0_.numRatings as numRatings164_, studio0_.numSEMKeywords as numSEMK45_164_, studio0_.numVouchersSold as numVouc46_164_, studio0_.phone1 as phone47_164_, studio0_.phone2 as phone48_164_, studio0_.phone3 as phone49_164_, studio0_.phoneImpressum as phoneIm50_164_, studio0_.premiumRecordUrls as premium51_164_, studio0_.premiumRecords as premium52_164_, studio0_.qualityPrediction as quality53_164_, studio0_.rating as rating164_, studio0_.ratingSources as ratingS55_164_, studio0_.reachabilityScore as reachab56_164_, studio0_.sectorNameScore as sectorN57_164_, studio0_.sectorOverlapScore as sectorO58_164_, studio0_.sectorScore as sectorS59_164_, studio0_.socialMedia as socialM60_164_, studio0_.sourcesWithNoAff as sources61_164_, studio0_.starsOverall as starsOv62_164_, studio0_.street as street164_, studio0_.successfulWebsiteLookup as success64_164_, studio0_.targetGroupTags as targetG65_164_, studio0_.teaser as teaser164_, studio0_.totalSrcEntities as totalSr67_164_, studio0_.totalSrcEntitiesWithNoAff as totalSr68_164_, studio0_.totalSummaryScore as totalSu69_164_, studio0_.videoUrl as videoUrl164_, studio0_.voucherUrls as voucher71_164_, studio0_.vouchers as vouchers164_, studio0_.website as website164_, studio0_.website2 as website74_164_, studio0_.website3 as website75_164_, studio0_.websiteAvailability as website76_164_, studio0_.websiteCount as website77_164_, studio0_.zip as zip164_ from studio studio0_ where to_tsvector('german'::regconfig, studio0_.companyName) @@ to_tsquery('german', $1)=true limit $2
```

Comment: "When I pass two words, like one two" what do you mean pass in two words? searchText should be a String..

Comment: @SpartanElite: sure, it's a String. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Show the actual SQL query text your program generates, from PostgreSQL' server error log or from Hibernate's query logs. That will show what's going on.

Comment: @CraigRinger: PostreSQL logs shows only following: see the edited queston

Comment: @Alex You need to configure Pg to log full statements - `log_statement = 'all'`. Or get the full SQL text from the Hibernate logs.

Comment: @CraigRinger `log_statement = 'all'` didn't help, it is already full log apparently. Hibernate logs produce the same...

Comment: @Alex That just doesn't make sense, with `log_statement = 'all'` it *must* log the SQL statement before the error. Did you reload the server? `pg_ctl reload`, `kill -HUP` the postmaster, or OS-package-specific equivalent.

Comment: @CraigRinger I changed the log filename to make sure the configuration is reloaded...

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I came up with was to escape searchText manually:

```
String escapedSearchText = String.format("'%s'", searchText.replace("'", "''"));
```

Comment: That changes your query to plainto_tsquery, which doesn't support Boolean operators and a range of other things.

Comment: My escaping? It doesn't change anything, because applied only to parameters.

Comment: Well it kind of does. Have you tested it? I am writing something similar and after adding the escape part that you have the | OR operator acts like an & operator.

Comment: Yes, I have tested it, it works fine with me: it simply escapes the search text. Could you post your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391535/handling-sqlgrammarexception-error-syntax-error-in-tsquery