# Handling SQLGrammarException: ERROR: syntax error in tsquery:

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

When using Hibernate with Postgres FTS, tsquery seems like the suitable thing. However, the subject exception seems to appear every time I try to enter "'" or some other mix of strange characters. It doesn't even seem to accept two words. And if you surround the strings with single quotes, then the Boolean operators like | stops working. I wonder if there's anyway to handle this exception. I have added throws to every single method but it seems like banging my head against the wall. Here's my code:

```
"SELECT FROM cat c where "+ args.get(0)+" @@ "+ "to_tsquery("+ args.get(1) + ")";
```

And this is what Hibernate generates.

```
"Hibernate: select fulltextse0_.name as name2_ from posts fulltextse0_ where 
  fulltextse0_.textsearchable_index_col @@ to_tsquery(?)=true order by 
    fulltextse0_.id asc limit ?"
```

arg0 is the name of the fulltext field and arg1 is a string that gets passed to it from a web form.

Comment: So you converted your code to use a parameter for the `to_tsquery` argument? The code you show above doesn't seem to match the SQL generated by Hibernate. If you were substituting the user input string directly into the SQL, you'd have it shown in the SQL, not inserted as a placement parameter (`?`).

Comment: @CraigRinger That code is part of a custom function that gets passed to Hibernate through JPA. In the JPA part, I actually pass an argument to the function that translates the query in Hibernate into Postgres.

Comment: That doesn't explain how `"to_tsquery("+ args.get(1) + ")"` gets turned into the parameterized SQL `to_tsquery(?)`

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails to follow a basic proper practice with SQL, namely: Never substitute user supplied data directly into SQL strings. This will open you to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) holes, and also cause a variety of exciting errors. You've discovered the errors, thankfully BEFORE someone exploited your database.

[Use parameterized statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. This is sample code and I know what you are talking about. But it doesn't solve the problem I have.

Comment: Really? Edit the question to show the actual SQL generated by your code, for working and non-working cases. Then we'll see. (Comment here when you've added the info).

Comment: Your code is not properly parametrized yet. I'll post a sample in a separate answer.

Comment: Wait a second, do you use PostgreSQLFullTextSearchFunction from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679264/setparameter-not-setting-proper-quotes? Could you post your entire code pls? How do you create your query?